# Docker: сеть, интерфейсы и контейнеры

Tags: linux, сеть, docker

У меня есть два сетевых интерфейса: eth0 - локальная сеть, tun0 - через него я хожу в интернет(поднимается и тушится с помощью самописного скрипта). На этой же машине стоит docker, у него есть свое собственное окружение для контейнеров. Из этого окружения наружу торчит интерфейс docker0, все контейнеры связываются с внешним миром через него. 
Тут возникает проблема: при поднятом tun0(при этом он становится дефолтным) контейнеры не хотят через него связываться. Как я понял надо как то перенаправить docker0 на tun0? Как это сделать?

Comment: ну, всё как обычно: https://unixforum.org/index.php?showtopic=103646

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отвечаю на собственный вопрос:
Проблема заключалась в том, что у меня не был указан dns сервер моей сети и по умолчанию был отключен ip_forwarding.
Для начала его нужно включить, раскомметнировав строчку:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

в файле /etc/sysctl.conf и перезагрузив машину.

Далее в файле /etc/defaut/docker редактируем строку:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-dns <ваш_адрес_dns>"
```

После редактирования перезапустите докер.

Comment: (Зануда mode) На будущее, после внесения изменений в sysctl.conf или в /etc/sysctl.d/* для подавляющего количества параметров ядра машину можно не перегружать. Можно сделать так:
`sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`
Или так:
`echo 1 | sudo tee -i /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`